# Uploading an image duplicates references that are used multiple times

Tags: discussion, support, editor, images

Okay, it's kind of difficult to explain in a title, so here goes. Imagine you inserted a URL into your post using the reference syntax, and then use that URL multiple times; the most common scenario for this being embedded images that link to themselves.

#### An example:

```
Diagram ([click to open in a new window][1]):
[![][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rVy.png
```

However, if one then inserts *another* image using the imgur upload function, the markdown looks like this:

```
Diagram ([click to open in a new window][1]):
[![][2]][3]

![enter image description][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rVy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rVy.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rVy.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKite.jpg
```

The image is added, but for some reason the existing reference is duplicated for each time it's used in the post body.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @balpha Well, it isn't really, seeing as it still works. It's just unnecessary, unexpected and a bit annoying when you want to update an image referenced this way, or its title text.

Comment: I don't think this is really a problem.